# Switch statement error in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm very new to Java (Just started this afternoon), and I've been trying to build a simple conditional calculator using switch statements.

The code I'm trying to make is quite simple. At first, ask for user's input (*Statement*), then the first number, and the second number.

The correct calculations will be made in accordance to the value of the input *(If it's 'Sum', then it'll be first number + second number. 'Sub' then first number - second number,...)*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scalc{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables//
        double fnum, snum, anum; //(First Number, Second Number, Answer Number)//
        String statement;

        //Input//

        System.out.println("Enter Statement: ");
        statement = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter First Number: ");
        fnum = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Second Number: ");
        snum = input.nextDouble();

        //Decision//

        switch (statement){

        case "Sum":
            anum = fnum + snum;
            System.out.println(anum);
            break;

        case "Sub":
            anum = fnum - snum;
            System.out.println(anum);
            break;

        case "Mul":
            anum = fnum * snum;
            System.out.println(anum);

        case "Div":
            anum = fnum / snum;
            System.out.println(anum);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("STATEMENT UNDEFINED");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Right now, though, it's stuck at *'Sub'*, for subtraction.

The programme runs normally, but when I input *'Mul'*, instead of multiplying the number, it subtracts instead. Same goes for *'Div'*. **Technically, the code seems to be stuck at subtraction and can't get any farther than that.**

I'm still a noob at this so ...

*Anyone?*

Comment: It does not subtract the number unless you enter statement `Sub`. But its dividing the number as you are missing `break` after multipliction.

Comment: Small advice for the division: it is always necessary to raise the exception in the case where the division would be by zero.

Comment: There is no issue, I compiled and checked it. The only issue is "Mul" command both multiplies and divides due to missing break.

Comment: You need to know that "sub" is not the same as "Sub".  Case matters.  @foxdie is correct - you're missing a break in the Sub block.

Comment: That's strange, I'm using Eclipse at the moment, and even with break the results came out wrong. It's probably the IDE, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `break` in under `Mul` case otherwise your next `case` statements will keep on executing until end of `switch` or `break`

```
 case "Mul":
    anum = fnum * snum;
    System.out.println(anum);
 break;
```

Comment: Ah, I checked it again and found it before your answer (Silly mistake), though the problem still persists. Even after I added a break, the result still turned out to be wrong (fnum - snum).

Comment: i don't think so , it's super stange , letme test it

Comment: @MatthewClifford i don't think so there's any issue , it's runs as expected but probably something wrong with your input , try `statement.trim()`, see [**see the ideone live demo**](https://ideone.com/FZaRRI)

Comment: @MatthewClifford if you are using command line then make sure to **recompile the code** to see the changes